# How to hide graph in qlikview

Tags: qlikview

I want to hide a graph in qlikview, display it when I want, but not delete it.

Your help is very appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Found it, if any one is interest , there is the link : http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/03/qlikview-container-conditional-enabling/

Answer (score 0):

Solution on website is not showing, so have included this response.

To show/hide an item in Qlikview, there needs to be a variable in place that can be altered. To create a variable, open the Settings Menu and then select variable overview. I would suggest a name of vShowGraph, create this and then click ok.

To set the variable on screen this can be done by either an input box or by way of button/trigger set on an item. For ease of user, I would suggest using a button.

To create a button, right click on your qlikview sheet anywhere blank, select "new sheet object" and then button.

To link the button to your variable, open the actions tab on the button, click "Add", choose Action Type of "External" and Action of "Set Variable". Enter the variable name (vShowGraph in this example). In the value box enter this script

```
=if(vShowGraph='Show','Hide','Show')
```

Your variable and button are now linked, you can now click it and it will change the variable from the values Show and Hide.

To hide your graph using this variable, right click on the graph and open the Layout tab. There is a box called "Show", change the radio button from Always to Conditional and enter the below formula.

```
=vShowGraph='Show'
```

Click ok and your graph will disappear if you haven't clicked the button. click the button and it will show.

If you have made any mistakes, you can still select the graph by opening the sheet properties and opening the Objects tab.